# ARC, strong и работа с сылками

Tags: objective-c

Есть свойство

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *view;
```

Если в коде инициализоровать свойство через _view, не будет ли это вызывать какие либо ошибки? Или инициализцию необходимо проводить через self.view?

Comment: По мне  ни только не должно вызывать ошбики, но вообще должно быть правильным.
self.view вызывает сразу и геттер и сеттер.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я предполагаю, что вы используете ARC.

За выражением `self.view = foo` в конечном счёте скрывается что-то вроде `__strong _view = foo`.

`__strong` является умолчанием при обычном присваивании (http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#property-declarations и, например, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859719/xcode-property-attributes-nonatomic-copy-strong-weak?rq=1) - поэтому смело можете использовать форму `_view = ...`.

НО! советую взглянуть на https://github.com/github/objective-c-conventions:

```
Never declare an ivar unless you need to change its type from its declared property.
```

откуда следует совет:

Если вам нужна запись свойства `view` только внутри класса, в котором вы его объявляете, тогда добавьте атрибут readonly к декларации @property и используйте только _view= внутри класса, если же вы собираетесь использовать свойство self.view для записи за пределами класса - не используйте `_view` и `_view=` вообще нигде - только `self.view` и `self.view=`.